# Add custom information to OpenVas reports

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I am using OpenVas to scan several different networks and aggregate those reports into RSA Archer.  Archer supports breaking hardware up into different Business Units/Divisions etc., and I would like to preserve that information.

If I know which, say, Business Unit, I'm scanning, is there a way to include that information in the report generated from the task?  I tried adding a `user tag`, but that doesn't seem to show up in the report, it just makes the report filterable/searchable by that tag.

Business Unit is just one example of the information I would like to add, and while I could conceivably post-process the report I would prefer not to have to do so.

So, is there a way to add custom information to an OpenVAS report?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is on-topic here. I think you're looking for an OpenVas forum for this level of support.